# Ignore globs that don't match anything

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I want to select all files in a directory that end with any of the following extensions: `txt`, `java`, `xml`, `csv`

Right now I'm doing like this:

```
echo *.{txt,java,xml,csv}
```

The problem is, if the directory does not contain, say, a `.java` file, the output looks like this:

```
f0030720.txt f0033510.txt f1028864.txt f1029056.txt f1068796.txt *.java f0905776.xml f1067014.csv f1067046.csv f1067056.csv f1067074.csv
```

That `*.java` item creates problems if I use `mv`, `tar`, or anything like that, since it's not actually a file. Is there any way for me to ignore any globs that don't actually match a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: And if you're using zsh, `(N)` at the end (e.g. `foo*bar(N)`) does it for just that glob. [And `(^N)` disables it]