# How to create a possibly empty array from filename glob?

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcards, array

With `zsh`, it is not difficult to create a *possibly empty* array from the results of a (possibly null) filename glob.  For example:

```
% pathlist=( /no/such/path/*(N) ); printf -- "%d\n" $#pathlist
0
```

With `bash`, however, the closest approximation I can come up with to the code above fails to produce an empty array when the glob is null:

```
% pathlist=( /no/such/path/*    ); printf -- "%d\n" ${#pathlist[@]} )
1
```

In this case, the `pathlist` variable contains a single entry, namely the string "/no/such/path/*".

How can I modify the `bash` code so that `pathlist` contains exactly one entry for every file (*if any*) that matches the glob?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding errors due to unexpanded asterisk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56051/22142) (Chris Down answers your question) or [Ignore globs that don't match anything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236149/22142) etc...

Comment: ... and btw, since you're a `zsh` user... the `nullglob` option is a [`zsh` invention, only added years later to `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/22142)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73793/discussion-on-question-by-kjo-how-to-create-a-possibly-empty-array-from-filename).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the shell option `nullglob`

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
pathlist=( /no/such/path/*    ); printf -- "%d\n" "${#pathlist[@]}" )
shopt -u nullglob
```

The Bash manual says the following about the `nullglob` shell option:

> If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

Comment: note `declare -p pathlist` is a nice way to dump an array variable.

Comment: @glennjackman:  Where would that fit into the answer?

Comment: Instead of the printf...

Comment: OP is using printf to simply print the number of elements in the array though, not a declare statement for it...If anything it would be better written as simply `echo "${#pathlist[@]}"`